# mqtt nodejs && flutter App Not Connect to vps

Tags: node.js, flutter

my vps server node.js code

```
const express = require('express')
const mqtt = require('mqtt')

const app = express()

var options = {
  clientId: 'test',
  clean: true,
  port:3000,
  connectTimeout: 400000,
  reconnectPeriod: 10000,
};

const mqttclient = mqtt.connect("mqtt://192.168.159.86", options)


mqttclient.on('connect', function () {
  console.log(`MQTT is connect! Your lights won't work... ouch!`)

})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('MiLight proxy hub is listening 3000')
})
```

my flutter app Code

```
    MqttServerClient client = MqttServerClient.withPort('192.168.159.86','test',3000,maxConnectionAttempts: 60)
      ..logging(on: false)
    ..setProtocolV31()
      ..logging(on: true)
      ..keepAlivePeriod = 20
      ..manuallyAcknowledgeQos1 = true
      ..useWebSocket = false
    ..autoReconnect = false..port=3000..secure=false
    ..disconnectOnNoResponsePeriod = 1000000;
    await client.connect();
```

error log flutter app code

```
I/flutter (10040): Header: MessageType = MqttMessageType.connect, Duplicate = false, Retain = false, Qos = MqttQos.atMostOnce, Size = 18
I/flutter (10040): Connect Variable Header: ProtocolName=MQIsdp, ProtocolVersion=3, ConnectFlags=Connect Flags: Reserved1=false, CleanStart=true, WillFlag=false, WillQos=MqttQos.atMostOnce, WillRetain=false, PasswordFlag=false, UserNameFlag=false, KeepAlive=20
I/flutter (10040): MqttConnectPayload - client identifier is : test
I/flutter (10040): 3-2023-12-30 10:14:04.805708 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - pre sleep, state = Connection status is connecting with return code of noneSpecified and a disconnection origin of none
I/flutter (10040): 3-2023-12-30 10:14:04.806011 -- MqttConnection::onData
I/flutter (10040): 3-2023-12-30 10:14:04.806110 -- MqttServerConnection::_ondata - message is not yet valid, waiting for more data ...
I/flutter (10040): 3-2023-12-30 10:14:04.806243 -- MqttConnectionBase::_onDone - calling disconnected callback
I/flutter (10040): 3-2023-12-30 10:14:09.808094 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - post sleep, state = Connection status is connecting with return code of noneSpecified and a disconnection origin of none
I/flutter (10040): 3-2023-12-30 10:14:09.808212 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - initiating connection try 11, auto reconnect in progress false
I/flutter (10040): 3-2023-12-30 10:14:09.808245 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - insecure TCP selected
I/flutter (10040): 3-2023-12-30 10:14:09.808306 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - calling connect
I/flutter (10040): 3-2023-12-30 10:14:09.808402 -- MqttNormalConnection::connect - entered
I/flutter (10040): 3-2023-12-30 10:14:09.809738 -- MqttServerConnection::_startListening
I/flutter (10040): 3-2023-12-30 10:14:09.809886 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - connection complete
I/flutter (10040): 3-2023-12-30 10:14:09.809978 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect sending connect message
I/flutter (10040): 3-2023-12-30 10:14:09.810034 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::sendMessage - MQTTMessage of type MqttMessageType.connect
I/flutter (10040): Header: MessageType = MqttMessageType.connect, Duplicate = false, Retain = false, Qos = MqttQos.atMostOnce, Size = 18
I/flutter (10040): Connect Variable Header: ProtocolName=MQIsdp, ProtocolVersion=3, ConnectFlags=Connect Flags: Reserved1=false, CleanStart=true, WillFlag=false, WillQos=MqttQos.atMostOnce, WillRetain=false, PasswordFlag=false, UserNameFlag=false, KeepAlive=20
I/flutter (10040): MqttConnectPayload - client identifier is : test
I/flutter (10040): 3-2023-12-30 10:14:09.810366 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - pre sleep, state = Connection status is connecting with return code of noneSpecified and a disconnection origin of none
I/flutter (10040): 3-2023-12-30 10:14:09.810976 -- MqttConnection::onData
I/flutter (10040): 3-2023-12-30 10:14:09.811096 -- MqttServerConnection::_ondata - message is not yet valid, waiting for more data ...
I/flutter (10040): 3-2023-12-30 10:14:09.811255 -- MqttConnectionBase::_onDone - calling disconnected callback
```

Comment: always format log messages same as code here